# how to run background job in web.py?

Tags: python, web.py

1. I use web.py to process incoming data by "GET" and "POST" method and uses `app.run()`. This looks will run in loop and never stop.
2. I also have a background job which detect port "9xxx" and process the incoming data, send msg to other servers to push msg to phone. I also uses a while(true) loop to do this.

How to integrate (2) into (1)? I'm confused.

I used to plan run (1) and (2) independently but there has data exchange so not convenience to code. how do you `web.py` users do these similar things?

Comment: Now I realized that maybe there's no way to run background jobs under web.py framework. just use multiprocessing to start background jobs and use queue to handle messages between web.py(or use uwsgi+nginx etc.. my task is little so I wanted to just use web.py) and background jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
nohup python web.py > web.log 2>&1 &
```

Check out [nohup wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) and [man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/nohup-1/index.html)

In production ,I'd like combine web.py with uwsgi and nginx.You can read [this](https://gist.github.com/TimSC/04993f1e3668d1decdfb) and have a try.And then I use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to restarts server after they terminate.

Comment: Thanks! my case is that the program(2) does not got GET or POST but other user defined format(of course, use tcp/ip and socket). it communicate with a remote device which send data to the server. I already make the server can listen and get the data but uses a while(True) loop to read/write data. But seems no good idea to operate it simply with web.py which is also do application.run()....

Comment: your answer is helpful! also with python multiprocessing I fixed this problem. use multiprocessing  to start 2 tasks that listen to other port to do something and use app.run to process 80 port POST/GET msgs in web.py. then use nohup to run them. Thanks!

Comment: @NickQian  If this helps,please accept this answer.